# Extract part of the string elements in an array using jq

Tags: json, substring, jq

I'm trying to extract part of the string in elements of an array, and create a new array with these extractions.

```
[
  "local/binaries/app-2.21.0.tar.gz",
  "local/binaries/app-2.20.0.tar.gz",
  "local/binaries/app-2.19.1.tar.gz",
  "local/binaries/app-2.19.0.tar.gz",
  "local/binaries/app-2.18.0.tar.gz"
]
```

Desired output

```
[
  "app-2.21.0",
  "app-2.20.0",
  "app-2.19.1",
  "app-2.19.0",
  "app-2.18.0"
]
```

Comment: As an experienced SOer you will appreciate that the best questions are those which mention some details about the specific difficulty encountered, often best demonstrated by one or more attempted solutions.

Comment: Thanks, @peak I tried using capture, but not sure if that is the correct function to do it, I will update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jq's `capture` function with regular expressions.

```
jq '[.[] | capture("(?<captured>app-[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)") | .[]]'
```

[Try it out on jq playground](https://jqplay.org/s/J1rxbFttze).

Documentation: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE

Comment: Woow, is working, I reviewed the docs about capture func, but it is confusing on how it works.

Comment: This function basically matches named regex groups (name defined as `?<group-name>`) and creates a stream of objects `{"group-name": "matched-value"}`.